# Powershell disk report error when disk more than one

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEJfY.png)i'm doing Script to check HD's status, when I execute the script and number of HD = 1 script done, but when the number os HD's ir greater than one don't show correctly the information (When I remove -Filter "DriveType=3"):

```
foreach ($servidor in $servidores) {

$diskinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $servidor -Filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object DeviceID, Size, FreeSpace

foreach ($disk in $diskinfo) {

    $i += "<tr>"
    $i += "<td>$($servidor)</td>"
    $i += "<td>$($diskinfo.DeviceID)</td>"
    $i += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskinfo.Size / $convertirGB))  GB </td>"
    $i += "<td>$([Math]::Truncate($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $convertirGB))  GB </td>"
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100) -le 15) {
            $i += "<td><font color=red> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100))  % </font></td></tr>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100) -gt 25 -and [Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100) -le 20){
            $i += "<td><font color=orange> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100))  % </font></td></tr>"
        }
        if([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100) -gt 35){
            $i += "<td><font color=green> $([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100))  % </font></td></tr>"
        }
}
```

}

Thanks so much :-)

Comment: What is wrong with the information. What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Sorry! attached image. https://ibb.co/eZbpdc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to `$diskinfo` in your loop (i.e. the entire disk collection), rather than `$disk` (an individual disk from the collection).

For example, replace this line:

```
if([Math]::Truncate(($diskinfo.FreeSpace / $diskinfo.size) * 100)
```

With:

```
if([Math]::Truncate(($disk.FreeSpace / $disk.size) * 100)
```

Comment: What a fail! TY so much boxdog